# How to check a string is not exactly mach with another string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use a javascript regular expression to check a string that does not exactly match with another?

For example I want not to match `'abc'`. Here are the result I should get

```
  input   |  output  
---------------------  
'abc'     |  not match  
' abc '   |  not match  
'abcd'    |  match  
'a abc d' |  match
```

I already used `'/^((?!abc).)*$/'`
but this will not match with strings like `'abcd'`,`'a abc d'`.

I'm allowed to use **only regex**

Comment: Regex excels with pattern matching, but for an exact match, why not just  `myString.trim() !== "abc"`?

Comment: No I cant. I can use only regex. because this is to match url routing

Comment: Can you do `console.log( /^abc$/g.test(str.trim()) ? 'not match' : 'match' );` ?

Comment: @pradeep Would `"def"` be a match since it isn't `"abc"`?

Comment: @TylerRoper yes "def" be a match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this regex should do what you want: `^(?!\s*abc\s*$).*$`.

It uses a negative lookahead for the entire string being some number of spaces, followed by `'abc'`, followed by some number of spaces again. The use of `$` in the lookahead ensures that the entire string is matched.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCAG8J/2)

Comment: giving a plus for using regex101.. that website is amazing. Very informative! I use it all the time :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes - I love it! As you say, the explanations they give alongside the regex are a great learning tool.